# Convert the 12c code into 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

This is in 12 c.How to convert this code into 11g? 
I've tried to do it using concat function but failed.Anyone can help?

```
 CREATE TABLE DimCustomer
(

,FirstName VARCHAR2(50)
,LastName VARCHAR2(50)
,FullName AS (FirstName || ' ' ||LastName)   --calculated column

);
```

Comment: That should work just fine in 11g if you remove the `,` in front of `firstname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove symbol `,` before FirstName

```
CREATE TABLE DimCustomer
(

FirstName VARCHAR2(50)

,LastName VARCHAR2(50)

,FullName AS (FirstName || ' ' ||LastName)   --calculated column


);
```

it working in oracle 11.2.4